# Is it safe to call size on a std container from another thread?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, containers, std, atomic

When one thread manages an `std::map` adding and removing things, may another thread safely call `size()` on the `map`?

Since there are no iterators involved, invalidation is not an issue.

In this case, I suppose the map is always alive. No object-destruction-at-a-bad-moment issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Size may involve traversal as it is not guaranteed to be O(1).